# Spring Cloud - circuit breaker at Zuul

Tags: java, spring, microservices, netflix-zuul, circuit-breaker

Is it possible to install Circuit breaker in Zuul proxy? The behaviour I'd expect is to stop forwarding requests (i.e. after 500 consecutive failures) and return error immediately. I don't want to provide any fallback methods etc. I just want to give service some time to recover.

I've tried to achieve this by adding `spring-cloud-starter-hystrix` dependency and `@EnableCircuitBreaker` with no luck.

Comment: If you are using Spring cloud's zuul implementation, I thought Hystrix was included by default. Check out https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/single/spring-cloud-netflix.html#netflix-zuul-reverse-proxy and https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/blob/master/docs/src/main/asciidoc/spring-cloud-netflix.adoc#providing-hystrix-fallbacks-for-routes

Comment: That's what I originally thought, but I don't think that's true: I've performed a test by calling one of my service endpoints which always fails (throws exception, returns HTTP 500). After sending 1000 and more requests in 10 seconds period the service is still getting called instead of returning error in gateway.